# Overwrite file in MLFlow on Azure ML

Tags: python, azure, mlflow

I have the same question that somebody already asked on the MLFlow GitHub page. But this is not on MLFlow's but on Azure's side of things.

I want to overwrite model checkpoints with the best model checkpoint at the current epoch, and not accumulate old checkpoints. Hence, I log the same thing again with MLFlow if the model has improved. This works locally, but on Azure overwriting is not possible. At least by default. I did not find anything in the documentation on that. Does anybody know if overwriting can be enabled for the Azure Machine Learning Studio model registry?

See this question: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/discussions/7686

And see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/train.py", line 30, in save_checkpoint
    mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model, "model/checkpoint")
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/pytorch/__init__.py", line 310, in log_model
    return Model.log(
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/models/model.py", line 487, in log
    mlflow.tracking.fluent.log_artifacts(local_path, mlflow_model.artifact_path)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 810, in log_artifacts
    MlflowClient().log_artifacts(run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 1048, in log_artifacts
    self._tracking_client.log_artifacts(run_id, local_dir, artifact_path)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 448, in log_artifacts
    self._get_artifact_repo(run_id).log_artifacts(local_dir, artifact_path)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/mlflow/_store/artifact/artifact_repo.py", line 88, in log_artifacts
    self.artifacts.upload_dir(local_dir, dest_path)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/mlflow/_client/artifact/run_artifact_client.py", line 97, in upload_dir
    result = self._upload_files(
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/mlflow/_client/artifact/base_artifact_client.py", line 34, in _upload_files
    empty_artifact_content = self._create_empty_artifacts(paths=batch_remote_paths)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/mlflow/_client/artifact/run_artifact_client.py", line 170, in _create_empty_artifacts
    raise Exception("\n".join(error_messages))
Exception: UserError: Resource Conflict: ArtifactId ExperimentRun/dcid.99783d0b-d340-4f2c-ab02-f4dd1c9d7dc0/model/checkpoint/python_env.yaml already exists.
UserError: Resource Conflict: ArtifactId ExperimentRun/dcid.99783d0b-d340-4f2c-ab02-f4dd1c9d7dc0/model/checkpoint/requirements.txt already exists.
UserError: Resource Conflict: ArtifactId ExperimentRun/dcid.99783d0b-d340-4f2c-ab02-f4dd1c9d7dc0/model/checkpoint/MLmodel already exists.
UserError: Resource Conflict: ArtifactId ExperimentRun/dcid.99783d0b-d340-4f2c-ab02-f4dd1c9d7dc0/model/checkpoint/conda.yaml already exists.
UserError: Resource Conflict: ArtifactId ExperimentRun/dcid.99783d0b-d340-4f2c-ab02-f4dd1c9d7dc0/model/checkpoint/data/model.pth already exists.
UserError: Resource Conflict: ArtifactId ExperimentRun/dcid.99783d0b-d340-4f2c-ab02-f4dd1c9d7dc0/model/checkpoint/data/pickle_module_info.txt already exists.
```

Comes from this line:

```
 mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model, f"model/checkpoint/")
```

Yes, I could do something like

```
mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model, f"model/checkpoint/epoch_{epoch_index}")
```

But I don't want to waste disk space for obsolete checkpoints.